# Windsor Resolve dependencies using a key

Tags: castle-windsor

I have registered multiple instances of an Interface using castle Windsor in the following way:

```
ServiceLocatorHelper.Register(
    Component.For<ISerializerAdapter>()
        .ImplementedBy<SerializerAdapter>(),
    Component.For<IDriver>()
        .ImplementedBy<FileDriver>()
        .Named(SerializationType.Binary.ToString()),
    Component.For<IDriver>()
        .ImplementedBy<XmlDriver>()
        .Named(SerializationType.Xml.ToString()),
    Component.For<IBroker>().ImplementedBy<Broker>()
    );
```

The dependencies are in the following way:

```
+ IBroker
  - IDriver
    types
    {
     - FileDriver
     - XmlDriver
    }
  - ISerializerAdapter
```

So in order to create a new object, this is the default constructor order:

```
IBroker broker = new Broker(new IDriver(new ISerializerAdapter));
```

**The question is:**
When I resolve a new IDriver using castle in the following way:

```
IBroker broker = container.Resolve<IBroker>();
IDriver driver = broker.Driver;
Assert.IsTrue(driver.GetType() == typeof(FileDriver));
```

The property IDriver is always of type **FileDriver**, while if I resolve the IDriver using the key it return the proper one:

```
IDriver fileDriver = container.Resolve<IDriver>(SerializationType.Binary.ToString());
Assert.IsTrue(fileDriver.GetType() == typeof(FileDriver));

IDriver fileDriver = container.Resolve<IDriver>(SerializationType.Xml.ToString());
Assert.IsTrue(fileDriver.GetType() == typeof(XmlDriver));
```

**How can I say something like this?**

```
IBroker broker = container.Resolve<IBroker>("Xml");
Assert.IsTrue(broker.Driver.GetType() == typeof(XmlDriver));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical scenario to use [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx).

Just declare factory interface:

```
public interface IBrokerFactory {
    IBroker GetXmlBroker();
    IBroker GetBinaryBroker();
}
```

And register it like this:

```
Component.For<IBrokerFactory>().AsFactory(),
Component.For<IBroker>().
          ImplementedBy<Broker>().
          Named("BinaryBroker").
          DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("BinaryDriver")),
Component.For<IBroker>().
          ImplementedBy<Broker>().
          Named("XmlBroker").
          DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("XmlDriver")),
Component.For<IDriver>().ImplementedBy<FileDriver>().Named("BinaryDriver"),
Component.For<IDriver>().ImplementedBy<XmlDriver>().Named("XmlDriver"),
```

The `GetXxx()` method name should match with `.Named("Xxx")`, thats all. Usage:

```
var factory = container.Resolve<IBrokerFactory>();
IBroker broker = factory.GetXmlBroker();
Assert.IsTrue(broker.Driver.GetType() == typeof(XmlDriver));
```

Comment: There's a spelling mistake in the line `Component.For<IBrokerFactory>().AsFactrory()`

Comment: Ok I corrected the mistake but had to add extra characters at the bottom to overcome some weird 6 character edit minimum...